# Moves website to subdirectory - Getting images/css paths to work?

Tags: .htaccess, filesystems

Ive got a website in a subdirectory but all the image, link and CSS paths are set like this:

"/images/error.png"
or "/help.html"
or "/css/styles/stylesheet.css"

I've tried a million different .htaccess things and tried setting the base href tag to the domain.com/subfolder.

I can't seem to get anything to work!

Also: There are hundreds of files in this system so I can't manually go and change all the paths to relative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you wrote: `Ive got a website in a subdirectory` I am assuming that you moved all images, css etc to subdirectory as well.

If that is so you can manage it using a simple RewriteRule. Create a .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT with this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
# if this is a link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# forward to subdirectory if it is not already subdirectory
RewriteRule ^((?!subdirectory/).*)$ subdirectory/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: @Tommo, the (?!subdirectory/) bit is a negative lookahead assertion, i.e. don't match if it already begins with subdirectory.  You need this to stop Apache returning a 500 because this would otherwise loop.

Comment: @TerryE: Thank you very much for adding well meaning explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative Paths (http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm)

So if your images are in

```
/SubFolder/Images/
```

and your viewing the file

```
/SubFolder/index.htm

Images/fileName.png
```

Will work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but there are hundreds of files in the system so I can't change all them to use relative paths.